# How to load Image from json into listview using Picasso

Tags: php, android, json, listview, picasso

im parsing data from sql to android using PHp. My PHP file works fine because im able to show a Text in a TextView.Now i would like to show an Image in an Imageview and try to download this image with the Picasso Client. For this i  tried the following Code:
     ArrayList> contactList;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ImageButton filteropen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aufklaupen);
    filteropen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout filter = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterloc);
            filter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageButton zu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zuklappen);
            zu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            filteropen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


    });
    final ImageButton filterclose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zuklappen);
    filterclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout filter = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterloc);
            filter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ImageButton auf = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aufklaupen);
            auf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            filterclose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    new GetContacts().execute();

    ;
}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Locations.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node


                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String street = c.getString("street");
                    String post = c.getString("postalcode");
                    String musicfirst = c.getString("musicstyle");
                    String musicsecond = c.getString("musicsecond");
                    String entry = c.getString("entry");
                    String opening = c.getString("opening");
                    String agegroup = c.getString("agegroup");
                    String imageurl = c.getString("imageurl");
                    String urlbt = c.getString("urlbtn");
                    String fsk = c.getString("Fsk");
                    String city = c.getString("city");
                    String lat = c.getString("city");
                    String lng = c.getString("lng");
                    String bg = c.getString("bg");
                    imageurl = image;


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("street", street);
                    contact.put("imageurl", imageurl);
                    ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**3
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Locations.this, contactList,
                R.layout.model, new String[]{"name", "imageurl"}, new int[]{R.id.namelist,
        });
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(String.valueOf(contactList.get(Integer.parseInt("imageurl")))).into(img);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

Unfortunately my app is crashing if i try the code above.

Thanks

Comment: post the crash log...from `Android Monitor`..

Comment: i think its because of this:  05-12 20:01:42.624 2474-2474/? E/hwcomposer: setGpuBoost:228: Can't open /sys/class/devfreq/gpufreq/max_freq: Permission denied

Comment: imageurl = image , What's the image variable doing here??

Comment: contactList.get(Integer.parseInt("imageurl"))? you are parsing it as an integer while storing at as a string.

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar what should i do instead of it